# How to fix Symfony update exception (2.8 -3.x)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I want already upgrade my Symfony from 2.8.31 to Symfony 3.x.
i changed the composer.json file to the following settings:

As well i tried for the Symfony Version a lot of different statements like "~3.0","3.0.*" and so on...

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "symfony/symfony": "v3.3.11",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.5",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.6",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.7",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.1",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3",
    "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
    "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.0",
    "jgm/tablebundle": "^1.3",
    "ali/datatable": "~2.0",
    "umpirsky/symfony-upgrade-fixer": "^0.1.6"

},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
```

}

But everytime i get the following error:

[image]

i changed several times the versions, but i really cant find the error. Till now i didnt found a clear answer, what this error message means and how i can fix it. i'm hoping  somebody from you has experiance with this topic and can support me.
The Composer shoud be up-to-date with the version 1.5.2.

Thanks for your support!

**EDIT**
The error message as text:

```
  Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.18 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.0.18 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.17 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.0.17 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no matching package found.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle 1.2.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.31], symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.1 2, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12,  v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9 , v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v
2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12,  v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6. 8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7 .8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24,  v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle 1.2.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.31], symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.1 2, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12,  v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9 , v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v
2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12,  v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6. 8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7 .8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24,  v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.14
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.15
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.16
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.19
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.20
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.21
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.22
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.23
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.24
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.25
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.36
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.37
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.38
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.39
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.40
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.41
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.42
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.14
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.15
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.16
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.17
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.18
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.19
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.20
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.21
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.22
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.23
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.24
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.25
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.26
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.27
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.28
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.29
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.30
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.31
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.32
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.33
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.34
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.35
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.36
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.37
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.38
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.13
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.14
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.15
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.16
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.17
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.18
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.19
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.20
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.21
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.22
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.23
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.24
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.25
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.26
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.27
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.28
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.29
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.30
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.31
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.9
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v2.8.31].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony ~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1 .0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9].
    - Installation request for knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle 1.2.*@dev -> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle[1.2.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: Post your terminal output as text. It is very difficult to read text on your image.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i edited!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your composer.json file. Note that symfony/translator: 2.0.7 doesn't exist anymore.

Change:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.0,<=2.2-dev" (or what do you have right now)
```

to:

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": "v2.2.0" (or a greater version)
```

**EDIT**

To update Symfony 2.8 to 3.* please follow this tutorial: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-3.0.md

Comment: I can't find in my composer.json file the package "symfony/framework-bundle", where shoud it be? Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer, please follow the tutorial in order to upgrade symfony 2.8 to 3.*